# How to open android native gallery app to select the image without chooser

Tags: android, gallery, default, native

I want to select Image from the SD-card through default (native app) application of the device "Gallery", without showing further chooser option to select third party application.

Currently to do the same, I am implementing the below code

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

But, using this a screen pops out saying **"Complete action using"** (chooser). with give a option to choose third party application if installed on the device (e.g file explorer).

My question is, how to directly open the native gallery without giving any option to user to select the app through which they can select the images.

What would be the class name to open the native gallery?

Comment: Check out this link http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android

Comment: @user1145009- I am getting the same result, Nothing different.